# Upload file with struts

Tags: jsp, file-upload, struts

I'm trying to upload a file with Struts. I have the html:file and the upload button, but I'm wondering if there's anyway of doing it without the button. I mean when I click on choose and then I select the file and when I click on open, the action is executed immediately.

```
<html:file size="100" property="file" maxlength="512" accept="image/tiff,application/pdf" />
    <button type="button" name="cmdFile" onClick="upload_onClick()" >
        Upload
    </button>
```

Basically what I want is that the upload_onClick() is executed right after I choose the file.

Comment: what about onchange in the file tag?

Comment: That will run counter to most user's UX expectations.

Comment: you can use <input type='file' onchange="upload_onClick()"/> ?